# Editing AJAX Call URL before post

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to add the data from the textbox 'postcode' into the URL 'VALUE1' and 'VALUE2'. I cant even show you any examples as i don't even know where to start.

```
<input type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" ><br>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get Postcode</button>

<p id="Addresses">No Postcode</p>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("Addresses").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.getaddress.io/v2/uk/VALUE1&VALUE2", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

How do i

Comment: You're looking for the wonders of string concatenation.

Comment: You also need to escape the value.

Comment: What is `VALUE1` and `VALUE2`? Are they both the value of the `postcode` input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enhance your code to use encodeURI. Also suggested is add some validation for inputs before making call: Looks at this fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/

```
<input id="text-box1" type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" ><br>
<input id="text-box2" type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode 2" ><br>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get Postcode</button>

<p id="Addresses">No Postcode</p>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
 var val= document.getElementById("text-box1").value;
 var val2= document.getElementById("text-box2").value;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("Addresses").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  var uri = encodeURI("https://api.getaddress.io/v2/uk/"+val+"&"+val2);
  console.log(uri);
  xhttp.open("GET", uri, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<input type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" ><br>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get Postcode</button>

<p id="Addresses">No Postcode</p>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("Addresses").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  var postcode = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByName("postcode")[0].value);
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.getaddress.io/v2/uk/"+postcode+"&"+postcode, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

This selects the element with the name attribute set to `"postcode"` and gets its value. This is then escaped for a URL string and added to your URL via string concatenation.

Answer (score -1):

it appears  you are not using JQUERY, but straight-stick javascript.
Here's an update.

Of note, you have one field, but two values.  that needs to be squared up first.

```
<input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" ><br>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get Postcode</button>

<p id="Addresses">No Postcode</p>

<script>
function loadDoc() {

 Value = document.getElementById("postcode").value

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("Addresses").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.getaddress.io/v2/uk/"+Value+"&"+Value, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense making request with `"No Postcode"` as value

Comment: wrong one.  I changed it.  Also, added the second value.

Comment: ok...but now you are trying to get innerHTML of an `<input>` as well as assign it to a global variable

Answer (score -3):

Below code will give you the value of the postcode field:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.getaddress.io/v2/uk/" + document.getElementById("postcode").value +"&" + document.getElementById("postcode").value, true);
```

Comment: The question is not tagged to jQuery.

Comment: JavaScript != jQuery. OP is not even using jQuery.

Comment: Right. I realized it's not tagged to jQuery.